# how to integrate stripe webhook with strapi

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, strapi

I am doing an integration of stripe with strapi and I have not given the solution, how should I configure my middleware in strapi to obtain the body of the raw stripe webhook request, but only for the webhook route without affecting the other routes

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  {
    name: "strapi::body",
    config: {
      includeUnparsed: true,
    },
  },
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```